# What had happen was

Tags: phrase-usage

Is saying, "what had happen was..."

grammatically correct?

Or, should I stick with, "what happened was..." ?

The first one is sometimes used jokingly but other times seriously.

So I just want to be sure.

Thanks,

Comment: *had happen* will **never** be correct: the perfect is formed with *HAVE* + a past participle, *had happened*.

Comment: You do hear "what had happen was..." sometimes in informal speech of the Southern US, I believe.  My wife is from Louisiana, and occasionally says it, although very self-conciously.  It isn't "correct", but it does occur in people's speech.

Answer (score 2):

> what happened was...

This is past simple: you are describing something that happened **before now**.

> what had happened was...

This is past perfect simple: you are describing something that happened **before some event in the past**. For example,

> Joe missed the flight: I wondered what had happened to him.

The departure of the flight is an event in the past: something  must have happened to Joe **before** the departure in order to prevent him from catching the flight.

Answer (score 0):

> what had happen was...

If a second verb follows *had*, with nothing in between, or *only* adverbs, then that second verb must be the past participle form of the verb because you are using past perfect.

So it needs to be:

> what had happened was ...

As far as the difference between *what happened* and *what had happened* - [it's complicated](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it/13261#13261), but essentially *what had happened was X* relates X to something else, either something else in conversation or something else the listener should know about.

> What had happened was the dog bit me, and then I ran away.
>
> A: What's wrong, why are you bleeding? What's going on? B: Well, what had happened was the dog bit me (relates to A's initial question)

If there is no "something else" then *what happened was X* will probably be clearer.

---

> The first one is sometimes used jokingly but other times seriously.

In speech, when saying *happened* there can be a tendency to not sound the *ed*, especially in quick speech.  Written out that way it's wrong and looks weird, though.